# How to develope IP Messenger in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, udp, asyncsocket

I am doing small demo on IP messenger in iOS using Objective-C. Can anyone help me how to do this ? The server side was developed in C#.Net. So I have to communicate with that server like IP Messenger. How can I approach ? Is there any demo projects in github or any othger place ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create messenger with IP communication you have to do socket programming at your server side and in socket programming use TCP communication for communication.

If you want to add pre-made library for this type of communication you can use XMPP protocol.

Reference for this

1. https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10649/An-Introduction-to-Socket-Programming-in-NET-using